# MySQL EAV query returns all entries

Tags: php, mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have a table that looks like this (except for a lot more entries) and I need to get the boatuid from all entries where taxstatuscode = Paid and taxpaidtoname = NO.
But I can't get it to work.

**Table:**

```
boatuid    slug              fieldValue
20         taxstatuscode     Paid
20         taxpaidtoname     NO
24         taxstatuscode     Paid
24         taxpaidtoname     SE
25         taxstatuscode     Not Paid
25         taxpaidtoname     N/A
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT a.boatuid
FROM tx_gcnwnxmlparser_boats_specs
LEFT JOIN tx_gcnwnxmlparser_boats_specs a ON (a.slug = "taxstatuscode")
LEFT JOIN tx_gcnwnxmlparser_boats_specs b ON (b.slug = "taxpaidtoname")
WHERE a.boatuid IN(20,24,25)
AND a.fieldValue = "Paid" 
AND b.fieldValue = "NO"
GROUP BY a.boatuid
```

As it is now it will return all the boatuid's that is in the IN() when it should just return 20.
I'm quite new to EAV and joins, so what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the keys when working with EAV is to join using the "entity ID" so that the attributes you select belong to the same entity.

```
SELECT a.boatuid
    FROM tx_gcnwnxmlparser_boats_specs a
        INNER JOIN tx_gcnwnxmlparser_boats_specs b 
            ON a.boatuid = b.boatuid /* "Entity ID" join condition */
                AND b.slug = 'taxpaidtoname'
    WHERE a.boatuid IN (20,24,25)
        AND a.slug = 'taxstatuscode'
        AND a.fieldValue = 'Paid'
        AND b.fieldValue = 'NO';
```

Answer (score 0):

Left join returns all rows from left table regardless of the condition think you are looking for inner join "TABLEA, TABLEB" or "TABLEA INNER JOIN TABLEB":

TABLE_A LJ TABLE_B

returns:

```
TABLE_A row 1 | TABLE_B row  (which meets condtion)
TABLE_A row 1 | TABLE_B row  (which meets condtion)
TABLE_A row 1 | TABLE_B row  (which meets condtion)
TABLE_A row 2 | TABLE_B row  (which meets condtion)
TABLE_A row 2 | TABLE_B row  (which meets condtion) 
TABLE_A row 2 | TABLE_B row  (which meets condtion)
.
.
.
TABLE_A last row | TABLE_B row  (which meets condtion)
```